# When you {complete / have completed} your service

Tags: word-choice, tense, past-perfect

Which one of the following two sentences is correct?

> 1.) When you **complete** your service you will retire on pension
>
> 2.) When you **have completed** your service you will retire on pension.

I think first one is not incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

#### TLDR: they are both fine but if this is a quiz, your teacher has a “right answer” in mind, and it’s number two.

---

## Here’s the difference

From your examples:

Let’s look at #2 first.

> 2.) When you have completed your service you will retire on (a) pension.

This is a **conditional**.  “When you have completed” is **not the past tense**,  it’s the future conditional.

And it’s followed by {`you will retire on pension`}. That’s the future too, so the two tenses match. That’s looking pretty good.

Now how about #1:

> 1.) When you complete your service you will retire on (a) pension

The first part is a present-tense conditional (you complete), meaning the ***very near future*** — and the second part is the future tense (you will retire).

So you have the *immediate future* followed by *the “regular” future.*

Why is there a change in tense?  No reason: it’s a small mistake.

This is a **very** small mistake, and not even the Queen of England herself would correct you if you said it in Her Majesty’s presence.

Here is the correction:

> 1B.) When you complete your service, **`you retire`** on (a) pension

The first part is a present-tense conditional, the second part is also present tense.  That sounds better.

***But:*** although this sentence is grammatically correct,  it sounds pretty informal.   The original #2 version— where retirement is in the future and so is the pension— is much more natural sounding.

Answer (score -1):

The first sentence is present tense "you complete your service". The second one represents someone who has already completed their service. I agree that the second one is correct being that you retire on pension only once you have already completed your services.

Comment: But is the first one wrong?

Comment: I'm not positive that it's wrong but it definitely sounds awkward.

Comment: Not awkward to me (BrE). They both mean the same thing.

Comment: @JeremyC I agree 100% that I would say either one with no regrets. But I think that one has a very small, pedantic error. . . answer posted.